# How to stop spring application on BeanCreationException

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application which is supposed to do a setup task on startup, and if this task fails (throws an exception) the application should stop completely.

I thought that this just works when the instantiation of the bean throws an exception, but this does not seem to be the case. What I am trying to do:

I created a spring bean (annotated with `@Component`). In the constructor I call another method that is doing the setup tasks and may fail.

If it fails, I get a `BeanCreationException`, but the application does not stop.

Is there a better way to do this?
How do I let the application crash if a (required) bean cannot be instantiated?

Comment: Well it should stop if it doesn't it is something you are preventing probably. That being said, don't do that work in the constructor but rather in an `@PostConstruct` annotated method.

Comment: That's what I thought, too at first.
Ok, thanks -- I will look into it searching for something preventing the shutdown.

Comment: If you want more help please provide your code in the question.